# Uniform continuity of $f(x) = 2x$

Tags: calculus

How do you show that $f(x) = 2x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ ?  Or is it not uniformly continuous?

Comment: Ever heard of Lipschitz?

Answer (score 5):

You check the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Definition_for_functions_on_metric_spaces).

> For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$, such that for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ the $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.

For $f(x) = 2 x$, take $\,\delta =\epsilon /2$.

Comment: Did you mean $\delta$ = $\frac\epsilon 2$?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the comment left by @The Chaz

> A differentiable real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ with bounded derivative is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

This is clearly(?) satisfied by your function $f(x) = 2x$.

Comment: But a homework problem, show $f(x) = 2x$ is uniformly continuous, would not be done by this method!

Comment: @GEdgar: But *is it* homework??

Comment: You mean can we just conclude, here $f(x)$ is real valued and $f'(x) = 2$ which is bounded so $f$ is uniformly?